# App bar is not showing in flutter scaffold

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am new to learning Flutter and Dart, I am following this tutorial "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPvVD8t02U8&t=28266s" and I did exactly like him, however, the app bar doesn't appear in my case I don't know why, Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Register'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

There are no errors in the console, The app runs and only "Register" text appear without the app bar.

I tried "Flutter clean" then many errors appear after, then they go away when I do "Flutter pub get", I don't know if that's relevant, Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you modify these two lines:

```dart
// remove
colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
// change it
useMaterial3: false,
```

Does it show properly?

Comment: Yes it works properly now, Thanks so much, I don't know why it worked, I still have a lot to learn...

Comment: Yeah, it was just Material 2 / 3 changes and the video was made on an older version when they didn't exist